# How can I stop a long URL from disarranging my table's column widths?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pls don't ask me to break up the URL across two lines. Pls see GIF beneath. The URL is https://books.google.com/books?id=x7VMDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=thomas%20ligotti&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=thomas%20ligotti&f=false.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the Table Properties dialog (Options button on the Table tab of the dialog) to display Table Options dialog, and make sure Automatically resize to fit contents is UNticked?

Comment: @Tanya Thanks! +1. You rectified my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to replicate Tanya's comment overhead to make it permanent.

> Did you check the Table Properties dialog (Options button on the Table tab of the dialog) to display Table Options dialog, and make sure Automatically resize to fit contents is UNticked? – [Tanya](https://superuser.com/users/535106/tanya) [Dec 2 '19 at 8:16](https://superuser.com/questions/1506466/how-can-i-stop-a-long-url-from-disarranging-my-tables-column-widths#comment2277087_1506466)